# nasm error: asm.6 label or instruction expected at the start of a line

Tags: assembly, nasm, dosbox

I am writing a simple code to add the elements in an array but the following error is showing **"b.asm:6: error label or instruction expected at the start of a line"**

I am unable to understand what is the error as I am new to assembly language.

Here is my code

```
[org 0x0100]
mov dx, array1    ;point dx to first number
mov ax, 0
mov cx, 4         ;load count of numbers in cx

5: add ax, [dx] ;add number to ax
add dx, 2       ;advance bx to next number
sub cx,1        ;numbers to be added reduced
jnz 5           ;if numbers remain add next

mov ax, 0x4c00
int 0x21

array1: dw 6,4,2,4
```

P.S: My file has been saved as **b.asm**. I am using windows 8.1 and DOSBOX because I have 64 bit system.I also have installed Nasm. I also tried another program to run which was also some simple addition, and it ran perfectly which means that error is in this code itself, everything else is working fine.

Comment: Labels should begin with a letter. To quote the [manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.1): _"The only characters which may be used as the first character of an identifier are letters, . (with special meaning: see section 3.9), _ and ?"_

Comment: @Jester wow, that solved the problem, but I don't understand that my course book has most of the labels as numbers. It means that book is wrong?

Comment: Is the book specifically written for `nasm`? Different assemblers use different syntax.